# What is a functional set-up for rails + webpacker development that solves CSRF issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I'm running Rails 5.0.2 on a project, looking to use `react-rails` and `webpacker` to handle things on the front end. I've only got a few components/pages that need to be dynamic, so I'm leveraging server-side rendering for a majority of the pages.

I've got, so far as `react-rails` is concerned, a pretty standard set up with `webpacker`. After following the instructions in their readme, I can load a page with CommonJS modules and whatnot.

**The problem**: Since webpacker is serving up its assets on `localhost:8080` and rails is operating on `localhost:3000`, the session cookie I start in the static half of the site isn't accessible to the dynamic half. I know I can probably solve this with an nginx proxy, but I was wondering if there wasn't an existing fix for this with the aforementioned tools, as this is kind of a game breaker for local dev!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack provides a proxy configuration when using their webpack-dev-server: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

This should proxy any request that isn't a static file.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i'd been looking for!